# How to trigger a function after clicking on a list item in a QListWidget? PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to know how to trigger the function "self.runEverything" when a specific item in a list widget is selected.
I tried this but nothing is happening because I am not entering the if-statement.

```
if(self.listwidget.item(0).isSelected()):
    self.runEverything(filepath)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check [QListWidget currentRowChanged signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#currentRowChanged).

So, depending on the thing you want:

```py
# example call
# QListWidget::currentRowChanged() emits an int value.
self.listwidget.currentRowChanged.connect(self.slotOrLambdaFunction)

def slotOrLambdaFunction(self, idx : int):
   if idx == 0:
     self.runEverything(filePath)
```

And then trigger stuff you need from the currently selected row in the widget.

You can also use `QListWidget::itemClicked(QListWidgetItem item)`.